# How do I edit the type in a field set?

Tags: custom-fields

I am trying to link a field to specific types of cases.  there id a field already set up which is linked to the wrong cases and I need to change it.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm interpreting your question as "I have a set of custom fields that are configured to only appear for a specific case type, and I want to change it so they appear for a different case type".

At Administer - Customize - Custom Fields, you'll see the list of field sets. Each one has a "more" link on the far right. Click there and pick "Settings". Then you can change which case types the set appears for.